# How to know the data type of my CSV file column in JAVA

Tags: java, csv, types

How to know the data type of my CSV file column in JAVA while inserting the csv file data into mysql.

Comment: Agree on some format, don't accept random input.

Comment: Just for the record: that other answer you got ... won't get you too far. Keep in mind: either you rely on importing data manually (and then **you** have to make sure that all the excel types are correct), or you rely that Excel automatism does the right thing (which might be possible, but depending on your data). In other words: the only thing the other solution says (in essence) is to add *missing meta information* manually. When you can do that easily, you could also code it in Java ... no need for the conversion to xls then. If it is not "done easily" ... what help is xls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you don't.

This is meta information. When you process data you don't know about, you can apply heuristics (like checking if a string could be a date), but there is no way to reliable acquire that meta information when it is missing.

Comment: So how can i validate my csv file data while uploading on mysql.

Comment: That is another question. You should read your data and then manually validate your data, like using Apache Commons CSV or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check CSV file data type but indirectly.
First of all you have to convert your CSV file in XLX or XLSX format. then you can check your CSV file data type

Comment: Sorry, but that is only half of the truth. You see, unless you do that manually, you have to really on Excel to *detect* the most appropriate type. Honestly, your answer is to "take the CSV file, and add the meta information by turning the data into something that contains types".